# Why this double value cannot be converted

Tags: c#, date

In the above code, I am getting the date data from SpreadsheetDocument. The exampled date cannot be converted.
But other dates can be converted.

Why cant i convert this date and how can I convert it in different way?

```
DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse("05.09.1977"));
```

I want to convert this string to DateTime with this.

Comment: "05.09.1977" is not something that can be converted to a `double`, try to parse it directly to a `DateTime`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Just use DateTime.Parse("05.09.1977") which defaults to a DateTime with day one 1/1/1.  If you want a OLE date where day one is 1/1/1900 then take the DateTime object and use ToOADate.

Comment: Why it has +2 ? he is asking why something which is not double can't be parsed to double ...

Comment: Instead trying `string_with_date -> double -> date` you should `string_with_date -> date`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"05.09.1977` is not a valid `double`. It looks like it's an actual date (either MONTH.DAY.YEAR or DAY.MONTH.YEAR).

To parse it to a `DateTime` use either:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("05.09.1977", "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or

```
DateTime.ParseExact("05.09.1977", "MM.dd.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 3):

This way:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("05.09.1977", "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Output:

> 05/09/1977 00:00:00

Comment: You are assuming 05 is the day and 09 is the month, it could be just the other way. I'm voting in favor of Sean's answer

Answer (score 1):

according to the 
[DateTime.FromOADate(Double) method doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_FromOADate_System_Double_)

Returns a DateTime equivalent to the specified OLE Automation Date.

> public static DateTime FromOADate (double d);
>
> Parameters
>
> d
>       Double
>
> An OLE Automation Date value.

so, you have to pass a double as argument

but double.Parse("05.09.1977")???

how can that be a double??

that is the reason